# How do I filter through commands when I use help in cmd?

Tags: python, cmd, command-line-interface

Since I have imported `cmd` into my project, I get a lot of unnecessary commands that I do not need. When I am in the interpreter and simply type `help`, I get all of my defs listed, and a bunch of these other commands. Is there a way to filter those so that when I type `help` I only get the list of the commands that I have made and not any pre-made/external ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc on the [cmd](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/cmd.html) module:

> With no argument, `do_help()` lists all available help topics (that is,
>   all commands with corresponding `help_*()` methods or commands that have
>   docstrings), and also lists any undocumented commands.

You just need to override the `do_help()` method in your `cmd` subclass like this:

```
def do_help(self, arg):
    """Provide help information"""
    # if arg is present, print help for specific function
    # otherwise print general help message
```